# How to prevent to insert duplicate value using multi threading

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

I developed a multithread application which insert some data inside a database.
Suppose I have the following situation:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddTeams());
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddTable());
}
```

as you can see I call two different methods which insert data into a db, the problem is that each method need to check if a specific record exists in a particular table:

```
public void AddTeams()
{
    //Pseudo code:
    //Check if a team with id 1249 exist in the table team
    //if not exist in the table team, insert the team with id 1249
    //then insert the record attached with an `FK` to the team table.
}
```

the same thing happen to `AddTable`, so sometimes I get this error:

> 'Duplicate entry '1249' for key 'PRIMARY

because the checking fails on the `AddTable` method, the reason of the failure is the parallelization that I used, for summarize: a time problem.

How can I manage this?

The only way that come to my mind is to handle the exception, but I don't like this approach.

Comment: Make the service single-threaded, handle the exception, or wrap the logic in a stored procedure that gracefully performs the insert.

Comment: @DanWilson how the wrap procedure should work?

Comment: Starting with the fact that you're using [`StartNew` (don't)](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), through the fact that you're not just making this code asynchronous, up to the point where you're adding thread-management overhead for a run-once task: this smells really bad. Possibly an X-Y problem. What are you trying (or what did someone tell you you have) to do?

Comment: @MarcL. the task are wrapped in a foreach that's why I need to shunt multiple thread. The main question is: how to handle record duplication (for prevent the error above) with multi threading?

Comment: @utop That is not a reason for multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to not parallelize the query to get the team and create it if necessary.  You don't want or need to do it twice, there's only ever a need to do it once to begin with.  So get or create the team, get the primary key of that team, and then pass that to those two methods to each create a related object, and that can be done in parallel.